# Why are pgp keys limited to a number of bits?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, key-management, pgp, openpgp

I am wondering : why does pgp keys have a fixed number of bits. They can be 2048,4096, but why not 56000 or 23 bits ?

Is there a specification, or ISO, that was made to limit thoses Keys. Why?
If a giant super-computer with quantum-processors-thatcostbillions®TM if built tomorrow, how can I do to keep messages secure?

Comment: These are common-sized RSA keys. At least with GPG you can patch the source (if it is really restricted in the way you've decribed). I've seen people with 12k keys, so at least this should be possible. 2048 and/or 4096 are considered to be good enough for now. Also keep in mind that the key needs to be usable. There is already a performance decrease going from 2048 bits to 4096 bits, so increasing it further, will make matters worse.

Comment: I think there's a mathematical reason for this but I dont know enough to state it. My guess is that because of the looped operations when encrypting the plaintext the outcome ends up being a fixed size, but that there could be an algorithm that cycles in a different way and it renders "odd-lengthed" ciphers

Comment: 2048 and 4096 are bits, not bytes.

Comment: The reason is a trade of between speed (usability) and security. You can use 56K bits, but the duration of the calc takes a but longer. 23 bytes btw is not considered secure (when using RSA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're talking about limits for RSA keys, for other algorithms, different limits apply.

The limit is set as a tradeoff between security, performance (in calculation time and storage/transmission) and finally compatiblity. It is set during compilation of the binary, and while being 4k most of the time, there are very well other limits depending on the distribution of GnuPG you're using, and you can set arbitrary limits when compiling it on your own.

Larger keys provide better security, but for RSA this does not scale linearly, while calculation complexity does grow linearly or grows even worse (only for some operations involving your private key, verification is rather inexpensive with RSA).

Another reason for limiting the key size is compatiblity; older implementations of OpenPGP might not be able to handle large keys. Especially for keys larger than 8k, even GnuPG breaks on a reasonable variety of systems. Generally, GnuPG will handle larger keys than it is "able" to create.